# Magento 2: js-translation.json not generating in pub folder

Tags: magento2.2, js-translation

On running setup: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command,

> js-translation.json is not generating in
>   "pub/static/frontend/theme_vendor/theme_name/en_US/--"

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: It may permission issue. Please confirm 777 permission given to pub, var and generated folder. Also please check is there any JS related error in your browser console.